# Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (784,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keras

I have an ndarray that looks like

```
[[array([0.        , 0.       ...       0.        ])],
                          ...    
[array([0.        , 0.       ...       0.        ])]]
```

where each sub array is a one-dimensional array of 784 np.float64 values

when I try to run Keras with a first layer that looks like '''Dense(32, input_shape=(784,))''' training_utils raises a ValueError because it thinks my array has a shape of (1,) when it expects (784,)

if I subscript the array I get `array[0].shape == (784,)`

what am I doing wrong here? I've tried transposing, using the keras.np_utils.to_categorical() function, etc.

I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm missing it

```
class netModel(object):
    def __init__(self, model, TrainingData, Labels):
        self.TrainingData = TrainingData
        self.Labels = Labels
        self.model = model
        self.model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    def train(self):
        self.model.fit(self.TrainingData, self.Labels)

y = mnConv.mnistConverter.convert("train-images.idx3-ubyte",
                                  "train-labels.idx1-ubyte", 60000)
md = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(28),
    Activation('sigmoid'),
    Dense(10),
    Activation('softmax'),
    ])
mod = netModel(md,td,lbl)
mod.train()
```

and the mnistCoverter function looks like:

```
class mnistConverter(object):
    def convert(imgf, labelf, n):
        f = open(imgf, "rb")
        l = open(labelf, "rb")

        f.read(16)
        l.read(8)
        images = []

        for i in range(n):
            label, image = [np.ndarray(10,),np.ndarray(784,)]#shhh, Ignore this
            lbl = ord(l.read(1))
            np1 = np.float64(1)
            np0 = np.float64(0)
            for i in range(10):
                if lbl == i:
                    label[i] = np1
                else:
                    label[i] = np0
            for j in range(28*28):
                image[j] = fit(ord(f.read(1)))
            images.append((lbl, image))
        f.close()
        l.close()
        return np.array(images)
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: `return np.array(images)[np.newaxis]`.

Comment: More complete example is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54662391/10418812

Comment: I see two brackets at the start, as though it was a list with one list inside.  Made into an array it might be (1,1) shape.  Are you sure all the inner arrays have the same shape?

Comment: The problem is that I don't set it to a list of lists...